# PHP resize image to minimum dimensions

Tags: php, image

I have 2 dimensions, (width & height) and I need to take another image, and resize it until both width and height are greater than the 2 dimensions. If the image is already larger than the 2 dimensions, I still need to resize it to be slightly larger than the given dimensions.

I also need to keep the image aspect ratio the same.

I've been trying the following:

```
$masksize = getimagesize($maskpath);
        // Reverse the sizes as it's landscape and we're always checking portrait
        $maskwidth = $masksize[1];
        $maskheight = $masksize[0];

        $currentsize = getimagesize($target_path);
        $currentwidth = $currentsize[0];
        $currentheight = $currentsize[1];

        $thumwidth = 0;
        $thumbheight = 0;

        do {

            $thumbwidth += 10;
            $thumbheight = $currentheight*($thumbheight+10/$thumbwidth);

        }while (($thumbwidth < $maskwidth) && ($thumbheight < $maskheight));
```

However it's not working, it only loops once and the width stays at 10.

So say for instance I have an image at 1000 x 2000, and the dimensions I have are 500 x 1000, I need the image to be resized to 510 x 1010 (i.e always bigger than the given dimensions, but only by a max of 10)

Comment: What if the aspect ratio of your image and your dimensions don't match? Like what if one is 3:4 while the other is 16:9 ? Also there's a typo in our code: `$thumwidth = 0;` should be `$thumbwitdh = 0;`

Comment: You have ommitted the purpose of this exersize from your question. Can you add this?